# Short story about the prison being our assumptions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Each day, the prisoner follows his guard from his cell to (someplace, perhaps questioning or torture) and then is led back. One day, the guard turns left, and the prisoner, impulsively, turns right, and after a time, reaches an exit, and after so many years of captivity leaves the prison, unopposed.

It's a quite short story, as it sounds.

Comment: How old is the story? How long ago did you read it, and in what sort of publication?

Comment: And can you elaborate on the fantasy/sci-fi aspects?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, Although I get that this doesn't sound like sf, neither does much of Sturgeon, Ellison, etc. I believe I read it in an SF anthology, though, partly because I generally don't read much else (not very much to my credit, I admit). user14111, It was at least a couple of decades ago.